# Continuous doubling weight vanishing on set of positive measure?

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

If $I$ is a bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$, let $2I$ denote an interval with the same center point but double the length.

A *doubling measure* on $\mathbb{R}$ is a (non-trivial, locally finite, Borel) measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(2I) \leq C\mu(I)$ for all intervals $I$ and some fixed constant $C$.

A *doubling weight* is an $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ function $w:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that $w dx$ is a doubling measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Question:** Is there a *continuous* doubling weight on $\mathbb{R}$ that vanishes on a set of positive Lebesgue measure?

Remarks:

- There are many singular doubling measures on $\mathbb{R}$, not arising from doubling weights.
- Without the assumption of continuity, there are doubling weights that vanish on sets of positive Lebesgue measure. In Section 1.8.8 of Stein, *Harmonic Analysis* an example (attributed to Journe) is given of a disjoint partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into sets $E_1$ and $E_2$ of positive measure such that the indicator functions $\chi_{E_1}$ and $\chi_{E_2}$ are both doubling weights. But this does not answer my question.

Comment: Nate Eldredge: Thanks for the comment. Your measure is not doubling, but I think you were confused because I did not explain what I meant by $2I$ for an interval $I$. I have added an explanation. Now it is easy to see your measure is not doubling, and in fact that a doubling measure can never assign $0$ weight to an open interval.

Comment: Oh, right.  Silly of me.

Comment: I guess the obvious first candidate to try would be $w(x) = d(x,C)$ where $C$ is a fat Cantor set.  Do you know whether that is doubling?

Comment: Nate Eldredge: This is a good suggestion, and modifications of it (e.g. raising to a power) work when $C$ is porous (hence measure zero). I thought about it a bit in this setting but couldn't quite see that it works. But maybe it does; I'll think about it further. I admit that mostly I'm surprised that, with doubling measures/weights studied for so long, that such a simple question would not be answered in the literature.

Comment: @NateEldredge: There has been a study of such weights coming from metrics and indeed they are doubling.@user100120: I'm also amused with the luck of study on "continuous" doubling measure, although there is an extensive literature on the so-called $A_p$-weights and absolute continuity w.r.t. Lebesgue measure (these weights are automatically doubling). The connection is via something called $p$-Poincare inequalities and reverse Holder. My suggestion is that you like to look into these Muckenhapt $A_p$-weights to see of they are continuous.

Comment: T. Amdeberhan: Thanks for the suggestions. The problem with Muckenhoupt A_p-weights is that (correct me if I am wrong) they cannot vanish on sets of positive Lebesgue measure. There are doubling weights which are not Muckenhoupt weights, however.